# Error: Process completed with exit code 1 despite successful build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-build

I am build an image using GitHub Actions with Cloud Build (note the `--suppress-logs` flag):

```yaml
- name: 'Build Docker image'
  run: |
    gcloud builds submit --config backend/docker/cloudbuild.yaml . \
      --substitutions=_IMAGE_NAME="mnist",_IMAGE_VERSION="v0.0.2" \
      --suppress-logs
```

The problem I have at the moment is that I am getting an error, as shown below, even though the build is successful. Running the command locally works fine too but for some reason the CLI returns a non-zero error code.

What's going on here?

```
Run gcloud builds submit --config backend/docker/cloudbuild.yaml . \
   ... <collapsed-details> ... 
 
Creating temporary tarball archive of 41 file(s) totalling 371.4 KiB before compression.
Some files were not included in the source upload.

Check the gcloud log [/home/runner/.config/gcloud/logs/2022.11.03/15.40.23.635776.log] to see which files and the contents of the
default gcloudignore file used (see `$ gcloud topic gcloudignore` to learn
more).

Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://dev-00-ebcd_cloudbuild/source/1667490024.26181-9244cfc1d92a484b9b4aaff7f4f27e1f.tgz]
Created [https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/dev-00-ebcd/locations/global/builds/6aa748e0-9a24-4c10-8aa4-37af33ea190d].
Logs are available at [ https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/6aa748e0-9a24-4c10-8aa4-37af33ea190d?project=599705029636 ].
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) 
The build is running, and logs are being written to the default logs bucket.
This tool can only stream logs if you are Viewer/Owner of the project and, if applicable, allowed by your VPC-SC security policy.

The default logs bucket is always outside any VPC-SC security perimeter.
If you want your logs saved inside your VPC-SC perimeter, use your own bucket.
See https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134928412) in Google since 2019 about permissions required to access the logs. It seems that the default logs option (using default Google-created bucket) requires Project Viewer role

In [comment #56](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134928412#comment56), Google provides a [link](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs) to the documentation with the alternatives to store the log:

- Store build logs only in Logging
- Store build logs in the default Google-created bucket
- Store build logs in a user-created bucket

I've tested the first option (only in Logging) including the following lines in cloudbuild.yaml file

```
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

And the build finishes correctly without errors